# If $f$ is holomorphic and $f'(z) \neq 0$, then all zeroes of $f$ are simple and positive.

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

I am learning to integrate in forms and this problem is from *Differential Forms and Applications*  (DoCarmo). (Cap 2. Ex 6.d)
I would like to clarify that I don't know complex analysis, just the basics.

If $f$ is holomorphic in $U$ and $f'(z) \neq 0, z \in U$, then (1) all zeroes of $f$ are simple and positive; furthermore, if $D \subset U$ is a disk such that there are no zeroes in $\partial D $, then (2)
$ \#$ of zeroes in $f$ $in$ $D = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial D} \frac{df}{f}$.

Then it gives a hint (that is basically the exercise)

(1) is a consequence from $$det(df) = u_x²+u_y²=|f'(z) |² >0 $$
I don't understand the final "=", and even without it, why that implies that the zeroes are simple and positive?.

(2) Now it give some hints for the other part and I can understand that.

But I have that problem (probably easy) in the first part, please help with this.

Comment: What is a "positive" zero of $f(z)$?

Comment: Usually we prove the argument principle / residue theorem from the Cauchy integral theorem and that $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} - \sum_{j=1}^m \frac{1}{z-a_j}$ is holomorphic, where $a_j$ are the zeros of $f$.